# Find the Joint Distribution of the Linear Combination of Independent Standard Normal Variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

Let X and Y be independent standard normal random variables, that is $X ∼ N(0, 1)$
and $Y ∼ N(0, 1)$. Consider the following linear transformations:

$U = aX + bY$ and $V = cX + dY, a, b, c, d ∈\mathbb{R}$

Find the joint density of U and V , denoted by $f_{U,V}$

I am confused about how to find the joint distribution, I understand that if $U,V$ are independent then $f_{U,V}=f_{U}*f_{V}$ but I don't think that is the case in this example, so I am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: You know that fact about independent random variables...did you look at the *proof* of that fact and try to mimic it for this case?

Comment: Hint: the distribution of $U,V$ is completely determined by expectation and covariance-matrix.

Comment: @drhab True, but why not remind the OP of the basic change of variable tool that, rather astonishingly, they seem to be lacking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse transformation is: $x(u,v) = \dfrac{du-bv}{ad-bc}, y(u,v)=\dfrac{av-cu}{ad-bc}$

Then apply the Jacobian change of variables formula:

$$f_{U, V}(u,v) ~=~ \begin{Vmatrix}\dfrac{\partial (x(u,v),y(u,v))}{\partial (u,v)}\end{Vmatrix} f_{X,Y}(x(u,v), y(u,v))$$